# Apache POI - intermittent colors for cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I try to create an xlsx file.

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    //create sheet
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Test");

    //cell style for data
    CellStyle dataCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    dataCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        //create row
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);

        //THIS IF
        //set intermittent background color
        if(dataCellStyle.getFillForegroundColor() != IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex()){

            //NEVER ENTER HERE              
            dataCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());

        }else{

            //ENTER ONLY HERE
            dataCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());

        }

        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(i);
        cell.setCellStyle(dataCellStyle);

    }
    try {

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();

    }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I try to make the color of cells to be intermittent. One white, one grey.

Cells with value `0, 2, 4, 6, 8` should have background white and others grey.

What is wrong at `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
if(dataCellStyle.getFillForegroundColor() != IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex()){
```

Must be something like:

```
if(i % 2 == 0){
```